# Unable to open the Web site: http://.. Forbidden

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, iis, iis-7, frontpage

Maybe somebody has already encountered with next problem:

When I try to open Remove Web Site using Visual Studio 2008 TS (File -> Open -> Web Site -> Remote) located on Windows Server 2008 SP2 Enterprise x64 (IIS 7.0) I'm getting next error:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7820/croppercapture1.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7820/croppercapture1.png)

I have access to the server. I added  user 'Everyone' with Full Permissions for that web site root directory, but it's doesn't helped.

Also I have installed FrontPage Server Extensions for IIS 7.0.

Comment: Issues with firewall and/or proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Being as its IIS7 its complex; there is a page on [learniis](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/) about it though.

Comment: All other sites on the same server are opens without any problems. But the main one - Forbidden !@#$%^&*